# How to place this green box to the end of the container

Tags: html, css

just need a little help with this html/css code, i'm working on this little project, how can i move this green box from left to the right as it is on the images.

[How it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDp60.png):

[image]

[How should it be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJLOJ.png):

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.container2 {
  border: 3px solid gray;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.purple {
  background-color: rgb(202, 117, 202);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.green {
  background-color: rgb(99, 151, 99);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.spacing {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="purple">

    </div>
    <div class="spacing">

    </div>
    <div class="green">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `align-self`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.container2 {
  border: 3px solid gray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.purple {
  background-color: rgb(202, 117, 202);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.green {
  background-color: rgb(99, 151, 99);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.spacing {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="purple">

    </div>
    <div class="spacing">

    </div>
    <div class="green">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 50px; 
    }

    .container2{
        border: 3px solid gray;
        width: 600px;
        height: 600px;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .purple{
        background-color: rgb(202, 117, 202);
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .green{
        background-color: rgb(99, 151, 99);
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        
        
    }
    .spacing{
        height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="purple">

        </div>
        <div class="spacing">

        </div>
        <div class="green">
    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```